# Book about a sea demon disguised as a man who killed by kissing

Tags: story-identification

This book was about a kelpie (or sea demon) who disguised himself as young man.

It killed girls by kissing them - when kissed sea water would run down their throat drowning them. The bodies would be found nowhere near water with seaweed about. A specific girl was target. I thought the book name was something with Lavinia. The girl was a descendant of someone known to the kelpie and I think he thinks she is her. And this woman from the past was Lavinia. I really loved the book as a kid. Would love to find it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like *[Watery Grave](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0440994195)* by Joseph Trainor.

From customer review:

> Sixteen-year-old Julie Monroe is haunted by visions of a sea-faring man who calls her Lavinia. Who is he and how is he connected to the death of her friend Cheryl Cowan?
>
> Julie discovers that for three generations Cowan women have died by drowning. Why does the spectral seaman haunt this family and why does Julie begin to remember another life? The answers lay at the bottom of Lake Superior, and time is running out for Julie and her friends.

Comment: Seems to be part of a series of teen horror novels (not connected to each other) called "Twilight: Where Darkness Begins". NO SPARKLES!

Comment: YES! YES! YES! You are awesome! Thank you! all these years i thought the name was "my sweet Lavinia" i think bcuz of that dumb vc andrews book..which was good ..but not as good as this one! Thanks for saving me endless more hours of frustration on the internet..you rock :)